# huawei ascend (m860) not recognized by adb on mac

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adb

I am trying to use a Huawei Ascend (m860) (this particular model from Cricket Mobile) as a low-end Android test device. I've already turned USB Debugging on from the device. I plug it into my Mac, run "./adb devices" from terminal and there are no devices listed.

Has anyone successfully connected this device to a Mac for Android development?

My setup:

Mac OSX 10.6.5
Eclipse 3.5.2 with the Android ADT plugin 0.9.9
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.26

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [thread at XDA-Developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=9900542) and [another thread at androidforums](http://androidforums.com/huawei-ascend/232290-proxoid-problem.html), you can't use adb with it because of some sort of lock.

You are probably better off rooting your phone first then installing Wireless ADB.

Also, for further questions on this you would probably want to ask on those forums (XDA-Developers and androidforums).